# Create New Field in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large table of messy data. It has numerous different values in the **use %** column where there should only be one. I want to create a new field which shows only *one use percentage per ID*; the lowest valid use percentage. null is not a valid use percentage. where there is only one use percentage and it is null, I want to change it to 0.

```
+--------------------------+
| ID | Current Use % Field |
+--------------------------+
| 01 | 20%                 |
| 01 | Null                |
| 01 | 0                   |
| 02 | 40%                 |
| 02 | Null                |
| 03 | 50%                 |
| 03 | 5%                  |
| 04 | Null                |
+--------------------------+


+--------------------------+
| ID | Desired Use % Field |
+--------------------------+
| 01 | 0                   |
| 02 | 40%                 |
| 03 | 5%                  |
| 04 | 0                   |
+--------------------------+
```

Please can someone suggest how to approach this complex query in access using SQL? I have been trying to manipulate this in excel but there are far too many records for my computer to handle.

Kind regards,

Comment: What is the datatype of the `Use %` field?  The inconsistency of the values (`0` vs `5%`) and the presence of the `%` sign leads me to believe it's a `VARCHAR` field...  is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Use)
FROM Table
WHERE Use <> "Null"
GROUP BY ID
```

The above assumes that the column is a text field. If its a number field, then change your where to: `WHERE Use IS NOT NULL`